# Не даёт объединить ячейки в строке

Tags: vba, ms-word, макросы, макрос

*"Отсутствует доступ к отдельным строкам, поскольку таблица имеет ячейки, объединенные по вертикали"*
Именно такую ошибку выдал мне макрос на просьбу:

```
tbl.Rows(i).Cells.Merge
```

Да, объединенные ячейки у меня есть, но в шапке таблицы. Можно ли придумать какой ни будь хак, что бы всё же i строки объединять можно было?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все разъединить, и сделать что Вам надо

Comment: @dSH Кхм, если есть вертикальное объединение в таблице, то не даст объединить горизонтально и наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

Из вопроса не ясно, что за объект стоит за tbl. Предположу, что Range, т,к. в случае Worksheet не вижу смысла в операции. Предлагаю так:

```
Dim tbl As Range, cel As Range
'...
For Each cel In tbl.Rows(i).Cells
    If cel.MergeArea.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        cel.MergeArea.UnMerge
    End If
Next
tbl.Rows(i).Cells.Merge
```